# Can the same data structure share more then 1 cache line

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, cpu-cache

I'm a newbie in low-level programming and my current work is about `Scala` development. But I just questioned myself with something (probably very stupid question) I could not find an answer just by myself using Google or commonly available profiling tools.

Can the `Integer`s (or any other data type 4 bytes size) share more than one L1-cache line.? I'm using `Haswell`.

From what I can tell... Yes, it can. Consider the following code:

```
;allocate 100 bytes with mmap
mov [rax + 62], dword -1 ; we misaligned the Integers which now has to share 2 cache lines.
mov ebx, [rax + 62] ; should result in 2 cache hit
```

Since cache line is `64B` aligned we put int at `64b-aligned-address + 62` position so 2 bytes of the int are in 1 cache line and the other 2 in another.

Is my understanding correct? If no, can you please help me to understand how it works in a nutshell. I'm not asking about cache coherence. My program is run on a single core in a single thread.

Comment: Two bytes can share the same cache line, likewise the two bytes can be on different cache lines.  Depends on how it is aligned.  More than two bytes can be in different cache lines depending on alignment.  The key is alignment, you are mixing languages/terms here.  If your cache line is actually 64 bytes and say you managed to put the 32 bit value at address  0x103E then yes two of those bytes are in one cache line (0x1000) the other two in another (0x1040).  But that is a lot of assumptions.

Comment: that is just purely using the lower bits.  The ways are determined with other bits and where striping occurs can affect you as well.  four bytes at 0x10000, 0x20000, 0x30000, 0x40000 etc could also all land on the same cache line depending on the design/settings.  talking generically not specific to x86

Comment: @old_timer Thank.you for the response. I may be wrong but I heard that for performance reasons we should preserve the alignment of data structure as a power of 2. Is that because of the value can be cached in different cache line (sorry if the question is dumb :(.

Comment: @old_timer If we are accessing data structure sharing 2 cache lines it will result in 1 or 2 cache hits?

Comment: @LindaTurasco You should align data at least on their natural boundary (e.g. 32-bit on 4 bytes,  64-bit on 8 bytes). This makes sure that if the data size < cache-line (if not you are doomed anyway and no instrs actually write >64B in one operation) then no cache line split will occur. The problem with splitting a cache line is that two lines must be fetched and merged.

Comment: @MargaretBloom It means when accessing data (even 4 bytes from 1 cache line) the whole line is fetched and all bytes except those 4 I am interested in are discarded? So if we have 16 ints in a single line and fetch them sequentially it will.result in 16 fetches of the whole same line?

Comment: Some microarchitecture can do an early-termination of the fetch, as soon as the chunk with the required data arrives, the instruction can execute. Others have the cache lines banked (divided into banks). But AFAIK, yes 16 different loads are 16 different instructions that do 16 fetches from the same line.  Accessing sub-line items requires a lot of ports. Andy Glew discussed something similar [here](https://sites.google.com/site/paulclaytonplace/andy-glew-s-comparch-wiki/array-port-reduction) and [here](https://sites.google.com/site/paulclaytonplace/andy-glew-s-comparch-wiki/arrays).

Comment: @LindaTurasco two cache lines means two separate hits or misses, each cache line is separate.